# Laravel Scout with TNTSearch driver filtering where clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout

I try to get the result of search queries with a `where` clause in the query using TNTSearch, but it doesn't work. The query didn't get the `where` clause.

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function getLigues(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('recherche')) {
        $ligues = Structure::search($request->recherche)->where('type_structure_id', '2')->get();
    } else {
        $ligues = Structure::where('type_structure_id', 2)->paginate(1);
    }

    return view('structure/ligues', compact('ligues'));
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get the filter query?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [this issue #59](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver/issues/59) on official [TNT Search Repository](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver).

See [contributors comment](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver/issues/59#issuecomment-270954859) on same issue.

**Where() clause yet does not support!**

There are other workarounds to achieve this testcase, for that check [issues](https://github.com/teamtnt/laravel-scout-tntsearch-driver/issues) on repository.